# How do I check the Model Name and Model ID for a Dynamic Role in a relationship-based route in LoopBack 3?

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I am [following the instructions](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Defining-and-using-roles.html#dynamic-roles) on LoopBack's documentation about using defining a custom role, and in every case I've found so far except for routes that are automatically defined as part of a relationship for a model, the `context.modelName` and `context.modelId` are populated. In this case, I have 3 models: `app`, `district`, and `app_district`; `app` has many `district`, and `district` has many `apps`.

I am creating a dynamic role that should allow users to only see apps and app_districts that they have access to. When I navigate to `/app/{id}`, this dynamic role resolver finds the `modelName` and `modelId` of `app` fine, however when i navigate to `/app/{id}/district/{fk}` I do not get a modelName; instead, I get `undefined`. The same goes for the `modelId`

Is there a way to get the model name of `district` in this case? Or `app_district`? I get the model name properly when directly going to `/app_district/{id}`.

Code snippet to show how I'm doing this:

```
Role.registerResolver("RegionAdminAccessingThroughDistrict", async function(
    role,
    context
  ) {
    const modelName = context.modelName; // always undefined in the above stated route
    if (!modelName || !context.modelId) {
      return true;
    }
});
```